# Combining two columns of three columns with one will remain

Tags: python, pandas

In an example dataframe like the one below, I want to combine two of the three columns with python. Is there any chance I can merge as follows?

```
   A B  C
1 a1 b1 c1
2 a2 b2 c2
3 a3 b3 c3
```

to

```
   A D
1 a1 b1
2 a1 c1
3 a2 b2
4 a2 c2
5 a3 b3
6 a3 c3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make column `A` the index, then `stack` the dataframe, drop the index at level -1, then call `to_frame` passing `D` to convert it to dataframe, finally rest the index.

```py
>>> df.set_index('A').stack().droplevel(-1).to_frame('D').reset_index()

    A   D
0  a1  b1
1  a1  c1
2  a2  b2
3  a2  c2
4  a3  b3
5  a3  c3
```

Answer (score 0):

using `.melt`

```
df1 = pd.melt(df,id_vars=['A'],value_name='D').drop('variable',1).sort_values('A')

print(df1)

   A   D
0  a1  b1
3  a1  c1
1  a2  b2
4  a2  c2
2  a3  b3
5  a3  c3
```

Comment: @ScottBoston i guess it is a close dupe of a general how to unpivot/melt a dataframe maybe we should close it ?

Comment: `df.melt('A', value_name='D').drop('variable', axis=1).sort_values('A')` pd.DataFrame has a melt method.  I upvoted you.  At least you get my 10 pts.